# When does a post become a Community Wiki post?

Tags: discussion, support, faq, community-wiki

Does an answer become automatically a Community Wiki when it is revised too much?

Are those who have enough reputation allowed to transform an answer into a Community Wiki's answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**As of April 2014, automatic community wiki has been turned off. From this point forward the only way for a post to become community wiki is**

1. For answers: the original poster clicked the little "Community Wiki" box to turn the post to CW, or through moderator action.
2. For questions: only through moderator action.

For details, please see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).

---

**Below describes the old behaviour**:

Copied from [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741):

> ### How does a post become a Community Wiki post?
>
> There are several ways a question or
> answer can enter community wiki mode,
> and most of these ways will occur
> automatically based on the rules of
> the system.
>
> Posts enter community wiki mode when
> one of the following happens:
>
> - The body of the post has been edited by at least five (**5**) different
>   users.
> - The post has been edited ten (**10**) times by the original owner.
> - The post's author checks the *community wiki* checkbox when composing the question or answer.
>   <sup><sub>Note that this checkbox is
>   only available to users with a
>   reputation of 15 or more.</sub></sup>
> - The post is edited by its original author, who when doing so opts to
>   check the *community wiki*.
> - An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki.
>   <sup><sub>Note that when a question is
>   made CW after answers have already
>   been posted, the existing answers are
>   not normally converted to CW
>   automatically.</sub></sup>
> - The question generates more than **30** answers (**15** on Super User). In this case, the question and all
>   answers will enter community mode, as
>   will any future answers.
> - A moderator has reason to believe that the question serves better in
>   community wiki mode.
>
> ** note that the rules outlined
> above are based on observations; the
> actual behavior of SO is subject to
> change without notice, and may well
> have done so since this was last
> updated...*